# How change data in database after getting close (SIGTERM, for example) command in Spring boot application using HikariCP?

Tags: java, spring, hikaricp, shutdown

I have Spring boot application, that goes to database using HikariCP (several threads use it).
The thing is, when application gets stop (SIGTERM) signal, it must go to database and change some data, after that it can be closed ("gracefull shutdown"). This logic is written in myShutdownHook `Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(myShutdownHook)`. So the app needs to use connection pool for that. But problem is that Hikari pool closes right after getting stop signal:

```
18:26:44,796 INFO  [SpringApplicationShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource: HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
18:26:44,798 INFO  [SpringApplicationShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource: HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
```

And context is closing before my logic is completed.
How can I go to database and change data there after getting shutdown signal, but before connection pool and application context closed?

Answer (score 0):

The way u register ur shutdownhook is at JVM level and does not block Spring's shutdownhooks (i.e. springs shutdown process is destroying it's own context).
Try using one of springs [shutdown hooks](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-shutdown-callbacks), they will wait.

Be wary though that ur shuwtdownlogic does not take too long...

Comment: I've tried using the PreDestroy shutdown hook but the Hikari connection is getting closed before this hook is completed.